# Can I install a hypervisor on the Windows system which I installed using a Boot Camp on MacBook?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, bootcamp

I'm using MacBook Air 2020. I installed a Windows system using Boot Camp Assistant a few days ago.

I'm not sure if Boot Camp is a type 1 hypervisor, but I heard that we can't install a hypervisor on top of another hypervisor. I was wondering, can I install a hypervisor like VMware on this particular Windows system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install a hypervisor on a Boot Camp system.

Boot Camp is not a hypervisor at all. It is just a completely normal, native Windows installation.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to install a hypervisor on top of another hypervisor, this is done routinely for testing and training on hypervisors.  The ability to nest hypervisors is often disabled in software as this poses a security issue and a performance hit on the virtualized machines, this is rarely necessary for virtual machines put to production use.

I believe you are confusing a hypervisor with desktop style virtualization software.  A true hypervisor cannot be installed on a Windows operating system because a hypervisor is a kind of operating system.  VMWare makes both hypervisors and desktop virtual machine software so you will have to be more specific which product you plan on using.  I assume you mean VMWare Workstation Player or VMWare Workstation Pro as those are popular VMWare products for virtual machines on Windows.  Either VMWare product should run fine on an Apple computer that used Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows.

Boot Camp is not a hypervisor or virtual machine of any kind, it is a set of utilities and drivers for making installation of Windows easier on Apple hardware.  It is possible to install Windows on Intel-based Apple computers without Boot Camp, and people will do that for reasons of customizing the install in ways that Apple doesn’t support.

It is possible to install a VMWare hypervisor on Apple hardware, then install Windows on to a virtual machine hosted by this hypervisor.  Apple and VMWare support doing this on some versions of Apple hardware and some versions of VMWare hypervisors.  That’s perhaps outside the concern of the question but I mention it for completeness sake.

I recall it being possible to install VMWare hypervisors on VMWare Fusion on MacOS, so I would believe it possible to nest virtual machines, VMWare or not, on the same hardware running Windows assuming that is the plan.  Nesting virtual machines requires this supported by the CPU, not being disabled by some kind of firmware security setting, and supported by the software doing the virtualization.

If all you are doing is one layer deep, no nesting, then you should be good to run any desktop/workstation virtualization software on any Apple product that had Boot Camp used for the Windows host OS, the guests may be limited in if they can be hosts themselves.  This is again not necessarily relevant to the original case but may come up for people with similar questions.

I believe that covers the big points.  Perhaps I can edit this down to be more concise with the question edited to be more precise.